# Auto height does not work in uiView in swift 3

Tags: swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I would like to adjust the height according to its content. 
[image]

Currently, I add "Height" in each `UIView`. These three `UIView`s are embedded in scrollview. 
I would like to set the height of "**Red**" color uiview into "**Auto**" . If I set that view into auto height and set the top, right,bottom,left specifically, I got error of "Scroll View". 

 So, I fix and add missing constraint, then `Xcode` will automatically define the height of Red `UIView`.

[image]

Let me explain, what I'm doing right now is that I add Segmented Control inside that Red UIView. Under that segmented control, there will be 3 Container Views. 

So, I set "Yellow" UIView to cover all these three container views.

So, Under "Yellow" container view, there will be... 
- 1 Container View together with collection view.
- 2 Container View together with collection view.
- 3 Container View together with collection view.

(I put collection views in each container views. So, there will be 3 collection view. I overlap these three container views)

I would like to extend the height of Red container according to the collection view content count. If collection view cell is more than 6 cells, then there will be three rows (each row has two collection cell). 
I have no idea of how to do this.
 Can anyone help me please to solve this problem?

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your `Autolayout` constraints. What content do you want to put inside the `UIView`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor, could you please check again my question? I edited it. Thanks a lot bro.